# eslint errors for onClick function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have navbar tabs and looks like code is working. But I cannot get rid of eslint error messages

```
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react';

const Tabs: React.FC = () => {
    const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(0);

    const handleTabClick = useCallback((index: number) => {
        setActiveTab(index);
    }, []);

    return (
        <nav>
            <ul className="tabs">
                <li>
                    <button
                        className={`tab ${activeTab === 0 ? 'active' : ''}`}
                        onClick={() => handleTabClick(0)}
                    >
                        <a href="/">Transaction</a>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button
                        className={`tab ${activeTab === 1 ? 'active' : ''}`}
                        onClick={() => handleTabClick(1)}
                    >
                        <a href="/">Overview</a>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button
                        className={`tab ${activeTab === 2 ? 'active' : ''}`}
                        onClick={() => handleTabClick(2)}
                    >
                        <a href="/">Budgets</a>
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button
                        className={`tab ${activeTab === 3 ? 'active' : ''}`}
                        onClick={() => handleTabClick(3)}
                    >
                        <a href="/">Wallet Settings</a>
                    </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
};

export { Tabs };
```

for every handleTabClick function error is

```
JSX props should not use arrow functionseslintreact/jsx-no-bind
```

if I change code like this

`onClick={handleTabClick(0)}`

I get error for onClick:

"(property) React.DOMAttributes.onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler | undefined
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler | undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1484, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onClick' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes, HTMLButtonElement>'"

how correctly handle clicking on tabs and change active tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there you can go through the docs :https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

which says you should have to add a esLint rule something like this:

```
rules: {
"react/jsx-no-bind": [ "error", { "ignoreDOMComponents": true } ],
}
```

This might help you to get rid of this issue :)